# How to let a non-signed in user access a restricted page only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a Rails 3.2 app that requires a user to be signed in (current_user) in order to access event pages, which are subdomains.  I'm using devise for authentication.

Is there any way to allow a user one-time access to an event page if I supplied the direct link to it?  I would then want them to be prompted to sign in (or sign up) if they try to access different event pages, or if they leave and come back at a future date to the same event page.

I've watched the guest account episode on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record), but it seems that a user could just continue logging in as a guest without ever signing up with this approach.

Here is my events controller code:

```
def show
    @event = Event.find_by_name(request.subdomain)
    if params[:id].present?
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end
    # if @event.present? and @event.videos.present?
      @video = Video.find_by_id(params[:video]) || @event.videos.first
    # else 
    #   @video = @event.videos.first
    # end
    # @json = Event.all.to_gmaps4rails 
    if @user = current_user
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Please sign in first"
      redirect_to sign_up_url(:subdomain => false)
    end
end
```

Thanks for any help/advice...

EDIT:  Just to provide some more context:

1. I will be trying to drive a lot of users to this one event page each week, and I'm not sure it's possible/practical to  hardcode separate hashes into the urls if I'm just sending out one link via social media and email etc.
2. As users will click on this link and go straight to the page in question, there is no action being triggered to create a separate guest model, so I think the answer will have to be session based, adding some column to the existing user model, but ensuring it is only used once per user.  I'm thinking maybe an ip address would work?

Comment: How is `current_user` being set? Are you using Devise for authentication?

Comment: Yes I'm using devise to set current_user

Comment: Understood. Please see my proposed solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most prescient solution is to create a session variable for guest users containing a boolean value indicating whether or not they have visited the page or not (and consequently enabling access if they have not visited, and vice-versa):

```
# in your controller
before_filter :check_guest, :only => :show

private

def check_guest
  # if user isn't logged in
  if current_user.nil? 
    # if user has already viewed, redirect
    if session[:viewed] == true
      flash[:alert] = "Please sign in first"
      redirect_to sign_up_url(:subdomain => false)
    # if user hasn't viewed, allow access, but flag as having viewed
    else
      session[:viewed] = true
    end
  end
end
```

Though using sessions is a de-facto approach to this particular issue, there are limits to its implementation:

- Session must remain valid in order of guest access to be tracked
- Browser-specific (thus multiple users on a browser will share the same session)

Comment: Thanks zeantsoi.  This session based answer seems like it will work best for what I need. However I've tried it, and it keeps redirecting me to the sign_up page, I assume because 'session[:viewed] = true' is automatically being set and so triggered.  How could I update it as true only once they're on the page?

Comment: Try evaluating `session[:viewed] == true` explicitly. I've updated my code to reflect. Does that make it work?

Comment: Great. It works.  I've adapted it a bit so it also persists beyond a session (see my own answer) but it's pretty much your solution, so I've accepted your answer as correct as it does solve my original question.

Answer (score 4):

One solution, rather than setting session variables, is to harcode a one-time hash with the url, like so:

```
http://site.com/event?access_id=AKJHDA23fdsank
```

Then, upon visiting the event, the access code is deleted. This would require management of access codes in the database, but has the added benefit of being foolproof.

You could quite simply create an api url for generating these links to simplify the process of sharing.

Most everything else is easily duped.

Comment: Thanks Damien.  It sounds like a good solution, but in practice I'm unsure it would work as I just want to send out one link each week, and I'm unsure how I could send out one link but have it generate multiple hardcoded hashes...let me know if I misunderstand your answer though, or if it could be used in that scenario.

Comment: @jfdimark you're right, it wouldn't fit that particular scenario. To make your session method more robust, you could log their ip, and other client data that isn't easily changeable. Course, with the right know-how it is still easily circumvented. I guess it largely depends how secure this functionality should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use feature_flags gem to set a boolean:

https://rubygems.org/gems/feature_flags

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a pre-built solution for this, but it shouldn't be too hard to implement. I'd do something like:

```
class GuestPass < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event

  # the guest_passes table has a `code` column that contains a long arbitrary string token
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :guest_passes

  def authenticate_guest_pass!(token)
    return false unless token
    guest_passes.where(code: token).first
  end

end

class EventsController < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_action :load_event, only: [ :show ]
  before_action :validate_guest_pass, unless: current_user

  private

  def load_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def validate_guest_pass
    pass = @event.authenticate_guest_pass!(params[:pass])
    if pass
      pass.delete
    else
      # redirect to sign in or whatever
    end
  end

end
```

Then you'd just generate `GuestPass` records and stick them in the links you provide: they'll look like `/events/1?pass=xyzzy`

(The code here could use some clean-up; I'm not saying it's pretty. But it's a first pass.)

Comment: Thanks gregates.  See my edit above.  As the guest will be clicking a link outside of the app, it won't trigger an action, which makes it impossible to create a separate guest_pass model, so I'm not sure this solution will work.

Comment: The thought was that you'd pre-generate these and distribute urls containing them. But I guess I see that your use case is slightly different than the one I was imagining - you want the links to be reusable, but for any specific user to work only once?

Answer (score 0):

This is my slightly modified version of zeantsoi's solution, with the added benefit that it persists even if the user quits their browser session.

```
def check_guest
  #if user is logged in
  unless current_user 
    @event = Event.find_by_name(request.subdomain)
    #if user has already viewed, redirect
    if @event.guest_ip_address == request.remote_ip
      flash[:alert] = "Please sign in first"
      redirect_to sign_up_url(:subdomain => false)
    #if user hasn't viewed, allow access, but flag as having viewed and store their ip address in the event model so it knows not to show the page again unless current_user
    else
      session[:viewed] = request.remote_ip
      @event.guest_ip_address = session[:viewed]
      @event.save!
    end
  end
```

Comment: This blocks all but one visitor behind the same NAT device, like, say, a Starbucks location.

Comment: Fred - good point. Is there a variation of this you can think of that would achieve the same but avoid blocking a whole cafe once someone from that NAT has visited the site?

Comment: You could store some value in the browser's DOM. I think modern browsers all support DOM storage.